# Too many redirects with mod_rewrite (at most one redirect?)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I want there to be at most one redirect using my htaccess file. Is that possible?

my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
#remove index/index.html
RewriteRule index\.html|index https://example.com/ [R=301,L]

#redirect to non-wwww and https site
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

#remove .html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

If I enter for example `http://example.com/foo.html` or `http://example.com/index` then I have two redirects.

If I enter for example `http://example.com/` or `https://example.com/foo.html` then I have only one redirect.

What I want:

- I want at most one redirect (see last two examples).
- If I navigate to the home page, then I always want the index/index.html to be removed
- All http calls should be redirected to https calls
- All URL which are called with www, should be called without www
- If I navigate to the subpage (`https://example.com/foo.html`), then only the html should be removed respectively the user can call the page without .html (`https://example.com/foo`).

Is this possible? Currently sometimes two redirections happen.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, based on your shown samples. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Apply https and remove www together for all requests here.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L]

##Server files with backend .html files.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]

##Deal with home page .html stuff here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index/index.html [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yet unfortunately this does not work. When I enter `https://example.com`, I get an infinite loop. Also when I enter `https://example.com/foo` I get an infinite loop.
When I enter `https://example.com/index` I get an endless redirect to `https://example.com/index`

Comment: @Sud0, I had tested these rules in my system. Is there any other rules apart from these mentioned rules in your htaccess? could you please do let me know.

Comment: Yes but no further rewrite rule. There are only rules for ServerSignature, AddDefaultCharset, cache rules and compression rules.